# ServiceStack async PreRequestFilters

Tags: servicestack

Is there any way to run PreRequestFilters that are async? I can see that there's been a number of async request filters added, but no async version of PreRequestFilters.

It would be nice to have an async version of PreRequestFilters so that we can run async tasks before any Request Filter Attributes. The only way I can see of doing that at the moment is to use GlobalRequestFiltersAsync and make sure all Request Filter Attributes have a Priority >= 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an async version of `PreRequestFilters` but you could use a custom [RequestFilter Async Attribute](https://docs.servicestack.net/filter-attributes) with a **-Priortity**, e.g:

```
public class MyAsyncAttribute : RequestFilterAsyncAttribute
{
    public MyAsyncAttribute()
    {
       // Priority -101, before any built-in request filter attributes
       Priority = (int)RequestFilterPriority.Authenticate - 1; 
    }

    public override Task ExecuteAsync(IRequest req, IResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```